# replace values of elements of a list using values of another list as a reference

Tags: python, list

I have the following 2 list

```
>>> a
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> b
['b a d c f g', 'a b b c d f', 'b c d c h']
```

and I want to update/replace **b** to looks like :

```
['b a d c var_1 var_2','a b b c d var_1','b c d c var_1']
```

i.e those key elements from **a** that it doesn't appear in the chain of the elements of **b**

I'm trying to convert **b** in a list of list an iterate over each element of the chain and compare against **a**, but I don't know if there is the proper approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totally understand your requirement, but my output is same as yours:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = ['b a d c f g', 'a b b c d f', 'b c d c h']


def replace_sub_b(sub_b):
    bl = sub_b.split()
    index = 0
    rl = []
    for c in bl:
        if c in a:
            rl.append(c)
        else:
            index += 1
            rl.append(f'var_{index}')
    return ' '.join(rl)


new_b = [replace_sub_b(sub_b) for sub_b in b]
print(new_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

```
set_a = set(a)
n = len(b)

for i in range(n):
    unknown_vars_mapping = dict()

    chain_vars = b[i].split() 

    for j, var in enumerate(chain_vars):
        # if the variable is not in a, store it
        if var not in set_a and var not in unknown_vars_mapping:
            unknown_vars_mapping[var] = 'var_' + str(len(unknown_vars_mapping) + 1)
        # if the variable is not in a, but already been seen
        if var in unknown_vars_mapping:
            chain_vars[j] = unknown_vars_mapping[var]
    
    b[i] = " ".join(chain_vars)
```